# Vue-jest can't find babel

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to test my vue components however I'm always getting the following error:

> Cannot find module 'babel-core' at Object. (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/babel-compiler.js:1:15)

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.6.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.6",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
},
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    moduleFileExtensions: [ "js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node", "vue" ],
    transform: {
        // process js with `babel-jest`
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        // process `*.vue` files with `vue-jest`
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
    }
};
```

You can see this behaviour [here](https://github.com/SuperDJ/vue-jest-babel-core).

When looking at the referenced file I can see:

```
const babel = require('babel-core')
```

Shouldn't that be `@babel/core`?

So my question is how can I resolve the error? Or is this an issue comming from `vue-jest`?

Comment: You probably just need this: https://github.com/babel/babel-bridge

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As suggested by [@JamesCoyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994081/james-coyle) installing `babel-bridge` solved it

```
npm i -D babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0
```