# Cannot find module 'babel-core' but @babel/core is installed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

After running `jest` tests, one of them is getting this error.

```
Cannot find module 'babel-core'

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/babel-compiler.js:1:15)
```

It's pretty straightforward. babel-core is not installed. But a newer version of babel-core (@babel/core) is installed!

Here I add my `package.json devDependencies`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.16.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.3.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "webpack": "^4.32.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
```

I want to know how can I get my babel loader or jest to recognize @babel/core and not babel-core. I read that babel-loader 8+ should do the work, but its not working as expected.

Didn't know it was a vue-jest problem, but thanks.

Comment: @babel/core and babel-core is different

Comment: I know, the are different versions of babel core. That's why I don't get it. Why is it asking for babel-core? and not @babel/core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue-jest can't find babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677044/vue-jest-cant-find-babel)

Comment: Babel 7 is not downward compatible with Babel 6. You need to upgrade all relevant dependencies to Babel 7 (`@babel/core`)  if you want to work with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`babel-core` is not `@babel/core` – they are different packages.

You should be able to get away here with

- installing the [`babel-core` bridge](https://github.com/babel/babel-bridge),
- or [switch to a newer, unreleased version of `vue-jest`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/blob/abcaaf2f0cc580d84f36c125110c7320d3f4a6b6/package.json#L32) which uses `@babel/core`.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors with babel-core, I think I'll try with vue-jest 4